# Is this statement grammatically correct? "Whether, how or to which god I pray, does not define me as a person and is none of your business."

Tags: grammar

Is the above statement grammatically correct regarding use of the word 'whether' or should I use 'whether or not' instead.

Comment: Remove the comma after "pray".

Comment: looks fine to me...

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the sentence, except (as @HotLicks says) the extraneous comma after _pray_.

Comment: The meaning is "whether I pray, how I pray, or to which god I pray does not define me as a person..." It's fine to use whether in that sense, so "whether or not" is not required: indeed it's unnecessary. You can probably argue either way about commas - there are many different views on how commas should be used.

Comment: There ought to be a comma after _how_; otherwise it gets lost among the _wh_'s and particles, and it's gotta be pronounced or nobody will understand it, so it might as well be in the print. English orthography needs all the help it can get, and leaving out important marks because they're named after a university is not helpful.